# Unable to get current user inside django rest serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm unable to get current user inside serializer. I have passed  context but still i get error like

```
"user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
```

#Serializer.py

```
class AddressSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        request = self.context["request"]
        validated_data["user"] = request.user
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

#Views.py

```
class AddAddress(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request):
        print(request.user)
        serializer = AddressSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request":request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, 200)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

#Models.py

```
class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField()
    address_line_1 = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    address_line_2 = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Address"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

I exactly don't know the problem behind this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the save() method

```py
    class AddAddress(APIView):
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    
        def post(self, request):
            print(request.user)
            serializer = AddressSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request":request})
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save(user=request.user)
                return Response(serializer.data, 200)
            return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Comment: Didn'et Get you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
request = self.context.get('request', None)
```

instead of this `request = self.context["request"]`

Comment: Hey i did try this and still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

It because `user` is required in serializer, mean that `user` data must be sent when post request.
From your code, you want to add the address according to the user who is logged in. So, `user` no need send by frontend. Try below:

```
class AddressSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {
            "user": {"read_only": True}
        }

    def validate(self, attrs):
        # make sure that you have passed request in context serializer
        attrs["user"] = self.context["request"].user 
        return attrs
```

Comment: Do i have to make user "read only"? Because I,m creating address with the user(Foreign Key)

Comment: `read_only` in serializers means that `user` no need to send by frontend. Are you want to creating address with the current loggin user? So we can passed `user` in `def validate`.

Comment: `user` still response in detail. I will remove second option in answer above.

Answer (score 0):

It is a foreign key. You need to assign the id to it, instead of the entire user.
validated_data["user"] = request.user.id

Event hen if the error persists, then the issue seems to be there is no "user" field in your validated_data. There is issue with the data you are sending in the request to the serializer. If it doesnt match the required fields, then validated data will be empty. Print and check your validated data, and also your request data.